# Node.js Stream, is drain working in this code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a big file using the following program

```
// this program will result in "JavaScript heap out of memory"
const fs = require('fs');

const printer = function () {
  const fil = fs.createWriteStream('./file');
  let i = 0;

  const writer = function () {
    while (i < 1e6) {
      if(fil.write("Hello man\n")) {
        i += 1;
        // console.log(i);
      }
      else {
        fil.once('drain', writer);
      }
    }
  }

  return writer;
}

const printty = printer();
printty();
```

I am not getting why this program is not writing data in chunks. Also the count seems to hang at around `1638`. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `drain` in the synchronuous loop and go on writing immediately. You have to give it time to execute.

A simple `return` can resolve this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const printer = function () {
  const fil = fs.createWriteStream('./file');
  let i = 0;

  const writer = function () {
    while (i < 1e6) {
      if(fil.write("Hello man\n")) {
        i += 1;
      }
      else {
        fil.once('drain', writer);
        return; // give the drain time to execute
      }
    }
  }

  return writer;
}

const printty = printer();
printty();`
```